# sqlite - filter data by now datetime

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with only one column with datetime values: I need to aggregate datetime by the minute and count how many records I have in the current minute (now). I try with this query, but work only if put a static value (eg. '2020-12-23 06:47') instead of "now" Thank you for all help!

```
select time from (SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime) as time, count(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime)) 
            FROM log 
            GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime)) as g
            where time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', datetime("now"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` clause to filter rows for current minute and then use `count` to count number of records as follows:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time) time, count(*) as cnt
  FROM log 
 where strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', 'now')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! i also set local time datetime('now','localtime') and now works all correctly